# Why stack behaved so strangely?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, riscv

I noted a strange behavior if a function takes an argument as plain struct like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};


int foo(struct Foo d)
{
    return d.a;
}
```

compiled **ARM Cortex-M3** using GCC 10.2 with **Os** optimization (or any other optimization level):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -Os -mcpu=cortex-m3 -o test2.c.obj -c test2.c
```

generates a code where the argument struct's data saved on stack for no reason.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <foo>:
   0:   b082        sub sp, #8
   2:   ab02        add r3, sp, #8
   4:   e903 0003   stmdb   r3, {r0, r1}
   8:   b002        add sp, #8
   a:   4770        bx  lr
```

What is the reason to save struct's data on stack? It never use this data.

If I compile this code on **RISC-V** architecture it will be more interesting:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <foo>:
   0:   1141                    addi    sp,sp,-16
   2:   0141                    addi    sp,sp,16
   4:   8082                    ret
```

Here just stack pointer moves forward and back again. Why? What is the reason?

Comment: You will have to ask GCC developers for the reason.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You could answer that to any question that asks why GCC does something.. You could also answer "ask the committee" for any question on why C does anything.

Comment: What are your results if you try other optimization levels?

Comment: See https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0042/latest

Comment: @DanielKleinstein well yeah, except that the C committee published very detailed standards about C while the GCC devs wrote some obscure mostly undocumented code... so they probably are the only ones to know about such quirks.

Comment: Then the question would be rather, why you actually pass the structure by value and not by pointer? Because this is why the compiler at first hand does the copy. If it later would optimize it away is a compiler implementation detail.

Comment: The optmization of such might maybe even happen later with the linker/location phase, when all the code comes together and path analysis and usage across multiple modules happen.

Comment: Generally there's an ABI calling convention stating if the caller or callee is responsible for stacking. When a function has external linkage, the compiler may not be able to divert from this calling convention because then the pushing/popping won't add up. I don't remember the details about gcc ARM so I won't post an answer. But generally the way to optimize such code is to inline, in which case you might have to give the function internal linkage (static) and place it in a header. Or as a rule of thumb, just never pass structs by value.

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer just doesn't "optimize it away", probably because its relying on a later part of the optimizer to handle it.

Try changing the code to

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

extern int extern_bar(struct Foo d);

int bar(struct Foo d)
{
    return d.a;
}

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct Foo baz;
    baz.a = rand();
    baz.b = rand();

    printf("%d",bar(baz));
    printf("%d",extern_bar(baz));
    return bar(baz);
}
```

And compiling at godbolt.org under the different architectures.   (Make sure to set -Os).

You can see it many cases completely optimizes away the call to `bar` and just uses the value in the register.    While we don't show it, the linker can/could completely cull the function body of `bar` because it's unnecessary.

The call to `extern_bar` is still there because the compiler can't know what's going on inside of it, so it dutifully does what it needs to do to pass the struct by value according to the architecture ABI (most architectures push the struct on the stack).  That means the function must copy it off the stack.

Apparently RISCV EABI is different and it passes smaller structs by value in registers.   I guess it just has built in prologue/epilogue to push and pop the stack and the optimizer doesn't trim it away because its a sort of an edge case.

Or, who knows.

But, the short of it is:  if size and cycles REALLY matter, don't trust the compiler.   Also don't trust the compiler to keep doing what its doing.    Changing revisions of the toolchain is asking for slight differences in code generation.  Even not changing the toolchain revision could end up with different code based on heuristics you just aren't privy to or don't realize.

Comment: I never saw bugs in modern compilers (all the bugs was mine). But the issue really looks like not enough optimized code i.e bug in optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

As per AAPCS standard defined by Arm, composite types are passed to function in stack. Refer section 6.4 of below document for details.

https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst#64parameter-passing

Comment: Small composite types passed in registers (rule C.12 in section 6.4.2). Here we have a small struct. And the question is why data copies from register r0 and r1 (as it was passed into function) to the stack inside the function?

Comment: Yes. you are correct, if arguments are less than 8 double-word size, then its still passed in registers. C15 rule comes into effect when its more than 8 double-word size. Can you compile without optimisation and check what you see?